# Need to find and replace/correct list from another df column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list let suppose F = [Jonii, Max, anna, xyz, etc..] and df which contains 2 column- Name and Corrected_Name.
[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6dWr.png)

I need to search each string from list into df[Name] and replace it with df[Corrected_Name]. For eg. in above, code will search list in df[Name] and if found which is "Jonii" then replace it with "Jon" which is from df[Corrected_Name].
So finally output will be f = [**Jon**, Max, anna, xyz, etc..]

Thanks in advance!! I am learner so pls ignore writing mistakes.

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this (Admittedly this is not the best way to do it):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Johnii", "Tommi", "Marc"], "CorrectedName": ["John", "Tom", "Mark"]})
names = ["Johnii", "Elizabeth", "Arthur", "Tommi"]

output = []
for name in names:
    updated_value = [cn for n, cn in zip(df['Name'], df['CorrectedName']) if n == name]
    output.append(updated_value[0] if updated_value else name)

print(output)
```

Comment: Glad it worked for your needs :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `dict` to do that:

```py
d = {k: v for k, v in zip(df['Name'], df['Corrected_Name'])}
f = [d.get(k, k) for k in F]
```

##### Reproducible example

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['foo', 'bar']], columns=['Name', 'Corrected_Name'])
F = ['a', 'aa', 'b', 'hello', 'foo']

# code above

>>> f
['b', 'aa', 'c', 'hello', 'bar']
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But in your example you know "a should be replace by b" or "b replace by c" but I don't have fixed list. There are number of list which I want to check. Thats why I asked to search words from list in df and replaced with 2nd column(corrected one). Pls suggest.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What part do I know? The `df` and `F` provided in the example are just that: examples. The code is generic and can be applied to to any other values, of course. BTW that's also why I asked for a reproducible example: so that we can help you more effectively.